# Find the lowest digit in a string

Tags: python

I have written a recursive function that returns the smallest digit in a string. Are there ways to better implement the procedure or are there different ways that using recursion allow us to do so in an easier way?

```
zeta = '14141539'

def m(s):
    s = str(s)
   
    if int(s) in range(-1,10):
        return s
    a = int(s[0])
    b = int(m(s[1:]))
    if a < b:
        return a
    else:
        return b
    
    
print(m(zeta))
```

Comment: `sorted(zeta)[0]`?

Comment: `'1' < '2'` is true already. You don't need int conversion.

Comment: For up to approximately 20 digits (depending on the actual contents of the string), `sorted(zeta)[0]` is generally more efficient than `min(set(zeta))`, but after that the latter will start outperforming the former. Considering how they're both fast enough for few digits, I'd generally use the latter.